# display output from a vim <F5> ".py script execution in the ipython console

Tags: vim, ipython

I am using gvim in interaction with IPython 0.12 on a linux box.

I would like to see the output of my *.py script displayed in the Ipython console, but I haven't managed to tweak the parameters accordingly.

Typically if I write something like

```
print sum([1,2 3])
```

I would expect the result to display in the console. Actually I only get a message displayed in the lower vim area giving an input number for the execution (In[2] say). But the display In[1] wouldn't change in the Ipython konsole.

Thanks for insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm one of the IPython developers, and wrote [vim-ipython](https://github.com/ivanov/vim-ipython/) (from which you're using `ipy.vim`).

The behavior you are seeing is simply a wanted feature that has not been implemented in IPython yet: ipython console, ipython qtconsole, and the web notebook do not currently print activity that they did not initiate. See the discussion on [issue #1873](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/1873) for this planned feature enhancement.

The `In[]` prompt will get update once you actually try to send a new command in ipython's qtconsole.

Answer (score 2):

What you said sounds like the expected result, but I think I know what you are going for.

You could use something like [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net) to send a command to a terminal session (using `send-keys`). So you would have one terminal that shows the output of your program, and another with vim. Vim would send a command (something along the lines of `tmux send-keys "python your.program^M"`) to the other terminal to run your script.

Another option you have is to have vim execute your script, but redirect the output to a file. Vim would execute something like `python yourscript.py > /tmp/out &` and your other terminal would be running `tail -F /tmp/out` so it will continuously update.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, actually I find out that %run file.py executed in the ipython shell will produce the expected output.

Comment: ...wasn't able to edit my previous comment.

Thanks for suggestions, actually I find out that %run file.py executed in the ipython shell will produce the expected output. Now I check the ipy.vim plugin to discover that <F5> actually runs def run_this_file():
    msg_id = send('run %s %s' % (run_flags, repr(vim.current.buffer.name),))
    print_prompt("In[]: run %s %s" % (run_flags, repr(vim.current.buffer.name)),msg_id)

Do you see an easy tweak in this function? Thanks